# Python mock.patch: replace a method

Tags: python, mocking

I'd like to replace a method in a class with mock:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class A(object):
    def method(self, string):
        print(self, "method", string)

def method2(self, string):
    print(self, "method2", string)

with patch.object(A, 'method', side_effect=method2):
    a = A()
    a.method("string")
    a.method.assert_called_with("string")
```

...but I get insulted by the computer:

```
TypeError: method2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

Answer (score 31):

The `side_effect` parameter indicates that a call to `method` should have a call to `method2` *as a side effect*.

What you probably want is to *replace* `method1` with `method2`, which you can do by using the `new` parameter:

```python
with patch.object(A, 'method', new=method2):
```

Be aware that if you do this, you *cannot* use `assert_called_with`, as this is only available on actual `Mock` objects.

The alternative would be to do away with `method2` altogether and just do

```python
with patch.object(A, 'method'):
```

This will replace `method` with a `Mock` instance, which remembers all calls to it and allows you to do `assert_called_with`.